# "Not authorized to authenticate" when logging in to Amadeus developers portal for self service APIs

Tags: api, authentication, amadeus

I have attached a screenshot of the error- I have authenticated my account via the email after signing up, but am unable to login. Anyone know a fix?[Pic of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHQ7v.png)

I tried contacting Amadeus directly, but no response.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing issue with the registration flow. Waiting for the fix. As a workaround you can try to register again choosing "Other" as Business area, that should work. In case you get an error like "User already exists" then simply try with a different email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to signup as ‘individual developer’.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).